# How can I split a string in Java and retain the delimiters?

Tags: java

I have this string (Java 1.5):

```
:alpha;beta:gamma;delta
```

I need to get an array:

```
{":alpha", ";beta", ":gamma", ";delta"}
```

What is the most convenient way to do it in Java?

Comment: I edited the title of your question so that it becomes more generic

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
str.split("(?=[:;])")
```

This will give you the desired array, only with an empty first item. And:

```
str.split("(?=\\b[:;])")
```

This will give the array without the empty first item.

- The key here is the `(?=X)` which is a zero-width positive lookahead (non-capturing construct) (see [regex pattern docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).
- `[:;]` means "either ; or :"
- `\b` is word-boundary - it's there in order not to consider the first `:` as delimiter (since it is the beginning of the sequence)

Comment: `(?=X)` is "zero-width positive lookahead", the non-capturing group is `(?:X)`. This would not work correctly with the non-capturing group...

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger could you explain more? It actually works this way (tested it), but I might have missed something

Comment: it works but the sequence `(?=X)` is not called "non-capturing group", or least not the simple "non-capturing group". It is called "zero-width positive lookahead". The "non-capturing group" is `(?:X)`. (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: ah, yes, thanks. It's a "non-capturing construct" that I meant. fixing it.

Comment: @Bozho - no - its a "zero-width positive lookahead".

Comment: @Stephen C - it's a zero-width positive lookahead, non-capturing construct :) see that all `?` are labelled that way.

Comment: I guess ... but that's like saying that "a mammal ate my homework".

Comment: @Stephen C :) anyway, I made it clrearer.

Comment: Good answer.  I wouldn't have known how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

To keep the separators, you can use a [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html):

```
new StringTokenizer(":alpha;beta:gamma;delta", ":;", true)
```

That would yield the separators as tokens.

To have them as part of your tokens, you could use `String#split` with [lookahead](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/PositiveLookahead.htm).

Comment: "StringTokenizer</tt> is a legacy class"

Comment: @Bozho True, but I think this particular use case of keeping the delimiters is not covered very nicely by String#split, which requires some detailed regex knowledge to get that.

Comment: true, it's a bit clearer with StringTokenizer, as it has the desired option as a boolean parameter. +1, the point about being legacy still valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply using patterns and matcher class in java regx.

```
    public static String[] mysplit(String text)
    {
     List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
     Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(:|;)\\w+").matcher(text);
     while(m.find()) {
   s.add(m.group());
     }
     return s.toArray(new String[s.size()]);
    }
```

Comment: Once the regexp djinni is out of the bottle, I prefer Bozho's solution.

Comment: Yup.. i agree... above was just an alt way of doing it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @param list an empty String list. used for internal purpose. 
 * @param str  String which has to be processed.
 * @return Splited String Array with delimiters.
 */
public  String[] split(ArrayList<String> list, String str){
  for(int i = str.length()-1 ; i >=0 ; i--){
     if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit((str.charAt(i)))) {
        list.add(str.substring(i, str.length()));
        split(list,str.substring(0,i));
        break;
     }
  }
  return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

Comment: This is just one more way! for who don't know about regex like me :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work with Java 1.5 (Pattern.quote was introduced in Java 1.5).

```
// Split the string on delimiter, but don't delete the delimiter
private String[] splitStringOnDelimiter(String text, String delimiter, String safeSequence){
    // A temporary delimiter must be added as Java split method deletes the delimiter

    // for safeSequence use something that doesn't occur in your texts 
    text=text.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(delimiter), safeSequence+delimiter);
    return text.split(Pattern.quote(safeSequence));
}
```

If first element is the problem:

```
private String[] splitStringOnDelimiter(String text, String delimiter, String safeSequence){
    text=text.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(delimiter), safeSequence+delimiter);
    String[] tempArray = text.split(Pattern.quote(safeSequence));
    String[] returnArray = new String[tempArray.length-1];
    System.arraycopy(tempArray, 1, returnArray, 0, returnArray.length);
    return returnArray;
}
```

E.g., here "a" is the delimiter:

```
splitStringOnDelimiter("-asd-asd-g----10-9asdas jadd", "a", "<>")
```

You get this:

```
1.: -
2.: asd-
3.: asd-g----10-9
4.: asd
5.: as j
6.: add
```

If you in fact want this:

```
1.: -a
2.: sd-a
3.: sd-g----10-9a
4.: sda
5.: s ja
6.: dd
```

You switch:

```
safeSequence+delimiter
```

with

```
delimiter+safeSequence
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you only have a finite set of seperators before the words in your string (eg ;, : etc) you can use the following technique. (apologies for any syntax errors, but its been a while since I used Java)

```
String toSplit = ":alpha;beta:gamma;delta "
toSplit = toSplit.replace(":", "~:")
toSplit = toSplit.replace(";", "~;")
//repeat for all you possible seperators
String[] splitStrings = toSplit.split("~")
```

Comment: 1. It's incorrect as it returns an empty 0th element. 2. It increases the chance of error due to duplications (ie ":" must be paired with "~:") 3. What if the special delimiter "~" is used in one of the substrings?

Comment: @Tony, I picked "~" as an example but any other unique delimiter could be used that was appropriate to the dataset available. I do not quite see how it increases the chance of error - perhaps you could clarify that point. I admit it does leave an empty 0th element which is a failing of this approach, but I wanted to present another option that did not rely on regex

Comment: What if the 'safe' character changes?  Or it's valid for one data source but not the next data source?  I've had that sort of thing happen.  Also, while replace() doesn't use a regex, split() does.  In some cases the special character will have to be specified differently in split() than for replace() making using a constant annoying.  For example, if I replace the "~" with a very common delimiter, the pipe '|', the code breaks as-is.  (Yeah I did that recently...Oh, the pain...) The split() has to use "\\|" while the replace() uses "|".  I don't mean to burn on you :-/

Comment: Not to worry about it Tony. I didn't think about that issue to be honest. Thanks for the tip