# how to replace parts of string using regular expressions

Tags: java

I am not a beginner to regular expressions, but their use in perl seems a bit different than in Java.

Anyways, I basically have a dictionary of shorthand words and their definitions. I want to iterate over words in the dictionary and replace them with their meanings. what is the best way to do this in JAVA?

I have seen String.replaceAll(), String.replace(), as well as the Pattern/Matcher classes. I wish to do a case insensitive replacement along the lines of:

`word =~ s/\s?\Q$short_word\E\s?/ \Q$short_def\E /sig`

While I am at it, do you think that it is best to extract all the words from the string and then apply my dictionary or just apply the dictionary to the string? I know that I need to be careful, because the shorthand words could match parts of other shorthand meanings.

Hopefully this all makes sense.

Thanks.

Clarification:

Dictionary is something like:
lol:laugh out loud, rofl:rolling on the floor laughing, ll:like lemons

string is:
lol, i am rofl

replaced text:
laugh out loud, i am rolling on the floor laughing

notice how the ll wasnt added anywhere

Comment: To clarify: Do you mean you want to iterate over words in a string and replace the shortword with its definition? E.g., replace "e.g., replace" with "exampli gratis, replace", over a long body of text? If no, please provide a before-and-after example.

Comment: i updated my question. the example is at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The danger is false positives inside of normal words.  "fell" != "felikes lemons"

One way is to split the words on whitespace (do multiple spaces need to be conserved?) then loop over the List performing the 'if contains() { replace } else { output original } idea above.

My output class would be a StringBuffer

```
StringBuffer outputBuffer = new StringBuffer();
for(String s: split(inputText)) {
   outputBuffer.append(  dictionary.contains(s) ? dictionary.get(s) : s); 
   }
```

Make your split method smart enough to return word delimiters also:

```
split("now is the  time") -> now,<space>,is,<space>,the,<space><space>,time
```

Then you don't have to worry about conserving white space - the loop above will just append anything that isn't a dictionary word to the StringBuffer.

Here's a recent SO thread on [retaining delimiters when regexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777546/how-can-i-split-a-string-in-java-and-retain-the-delimiters).

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using regex, this would work (taking Zoltan Balazs' dictionary map approach):

```
Map<String, String> substitutions = loadDictionaryFromSomewhere();
int lengthOfShortestKeyInMap = 3; //Calculate
int lengthOfLongestKeyInMap = 3; //Calculate

StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer(input.length());
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w{" + lengthOfShortestKeyInMap + "," + lengthOfLongestKeyInMap + "})\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String candidate = matcher.group(1);
    String substitute = substitutions.get(candidate);
    if (substitute == null)
        substitute = candidate; // no match, use original
    matcher.appendReplacement(output, Matcher.quoteReplacement(substitute));
}
matcher.appendTail(output);
// output now contains the text with substituted words
```

If you plan to process many inputs, pre-compiling the pattern is more efficient than using `String.split()`, which compiles a new `Pattern` each call.

(edit) Compiling all of the keys into a single pattern yields a more efficient approach, like so:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(lol|rtfm|rofl|wtf)\\b");
// rest of the method unchanged, don't need the shortest/longest key stuff
```

This allows the regex engine to skip over any words that happen to be short enough but aren't in the list, saving you a lot of map accesses.

Comment: I dont think |'ing every key in my dictionary is a good approach, because i then need to check what the key is before inserting my definition.

Comment: That's check is implicit in `substitute = substitutions.get(candidate)`.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing, that comes into my mind is this:

```
...
// eg: lol -> laugh out loud
Map<String, String> dictionatry;

ArrayList<String> originalText;
ArrayList<String> replacedText;

for(String string : originalText) {
   if(dictionary.contains(string)) {
      replacedText.add(dictionary.get(string));
   } else {
      replacedText.add(string);
   }
...
```

Or you could use a StringBuffer instead of the `replacedText`.

Comment: Are you implying that I explode my original text? Also, it seems like there is a lot of overhead here? Do you think that exploding the text and keeping these arrays is better (efficient) than using regular expressions?

Comment: In Java the String class is immutable, so once created and initialized, it cannot be changed on the same reference. So every replace calling would create a new String. 

The other reason why I suggest this implementation is because it is easy to read and understand. You just have to explode your big string into a list and keep this 2 lists in memory.

Comment: Thanks. I like your answer, but I used the other one.