# Splitting a String using Word Delimiters

Tags: java, string-matching

i have a string as below

```
a > b and c < d or d > e and f > g
```

outcome must be:

```
a > b
and
c < d
or
d > e
and
f > g
```

i want to split the string at occurrences of "and" , "or" and retrieve the delims as well along with the token.[i need them in order to evaluate the expression]

i tried using StringTokenizer as

```
 new StringTokenizer(x, "\\sand\\s|\\sor\\s", true);
```

but i dont get desired outcome.
i tried using scanner as

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(x);
        sc.useDelimiter("and | or");
```

this is able to split but doesnt return the delimiters.

please suggest.

i have given a , b , c above but there cud be words instead of a,b , c with spaces.
Updated example.

Comment: Your description implies using the Strings "and" & "or" as delimiters, but your output implies " " as a delimiter.  Please clarify.

Comment: doh! i give bad example as string..let me provide another example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777546/how-can-i-split-a-string-in-java-and-retain-the-delimiters

Answer (score 3):

This will split on "and" or "or" with any number of spaces surrounding the words.

```
   String test = "2 < 3 and 3 > 2 or 4 < 6 and 7 < 8";

    String [] splitString = test.split("\\s*[and|or]+\\s*");
    for(int i = 0; i < splitString.length ; i ++){
        System.out.println(splitString[i]);
    }
```

output

```
2 < 3
3 > 2
4 < 6
7 < 8
```

Comment: how to get the delimiter as well ?

Answer (score 2):

```
String delim = " ";
String[] splitstrings = yourString.split(delim);
for (int i = 0; i < splitstrings.length(); i++) {
    splitstrings += delim;
}
```

Comment: OP wants the delims to be returned as well. `split` wont return delims.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is a tool like [JFlex](http://jflex.de/) by the time you run into all the different permutations of white spaces and as your syntax grows. In the long run you will save time.

Answer (score 0):

A StringTokenizer is the only java standard class that is capable of returning the used delimiter as well as far as I'm aware. Just copied the regex from the OT assuming that it'll do what he wants (which on second glance I extremely doubt from his textual description, but oh well - just insert the right one)

```
    String input = "a > b and c < d or d > e and f > g";
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, "\\sand\\s|\\sor\\s", true);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
String str = "2 < 3 and 3 > 2 or 4 < 6 and 7 < 8";
System.out.println( ImmutableList.copyOf( str.split( "(?=and|or)" ) ) );
```

Output:

```
[2 < 3 , and 3 > 2 , or 4 < 6 , and 7 < 8]
```