# Java: How to split and keep delimiter

Tags: java, regex, split

I can't find the exact way to solve this issue I'm having.
I want to split a sentence which will have spaces and can have punctuation marks. I want to keep the words and punctuation marks and store them in a single array.

```
 Example sentence;
 We have not met, have we?

 Desired array;
{"We", "have", "not", "met", ",", "have", "we", "?"}
```

I'm trying to split the sentence in a single String split method.
I've looked through other related questions on stack overflow and I have't be able to get a regex which caters for me, especially for the question mark.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters

Comment: @Alex Conroy Try and look around and see if someone's asked a similar question first.  There's more than a few that cover this, like the above and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777546/how-can-i-split-a-string-in-java-and-retain-the-delimiters

Comment: Thanks for link @Tibrogargan, I actually looked up that question before hand but it didn't work for me.  I tweaked the solution(s) from that question and it worked with everything expect for the question mark, I was receiving error messages for the question mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try splitting with whitespaces or at the locations before non-word characters:

```
\s+|(?=\W)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS4oP7/1)

*Pattern details*: `\s+|(?=\W)` contains two alternatives separated with `|` symbol. `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespaces that are removed when splitting. `(?=\W)` is a positive lookahead that only matches an empty space before the pattern it contains - here, `\W` matches any non-word character (not a letter, digit, or underscore).

**NOTE**: If a non-word `\W` class is too "greedy" for you, you may use a punctuation class, `\p{P}` (`String pattern = "\\s+|(?=\\p{P})"`) to only split before punctuation.

[IDEONE Java demo](http://ideone.com/Tdq26v):

```
String str = "We have not met, have we?"; 
String[] chunks = str.split("\\s+|(?=\\W)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chunks));
// => [We, have, not, met, ,, have, we, ?]
```

**If you need to tokenize the non-whitespace/non-word chunks as whole units** (say, `?!!` as one array element), use this matching technique:

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("[^\\s\\W]+|\\S+");
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher("We have not met, have we?!!");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    list.add(m.group(0));
}
System.out.println(list); // => [We, have, not, met, ,, have, we, ?!!]
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/KxMlCM) and [a regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS4oP7/2).

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution and making it clear. 
Also cheers for the regex demo link, that'll be a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sentence="We have not met, have we ?";
String[] splited = sentence.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: That will only split the spaces, it won't split and keep the exclamation marks.

Comment: Can you please expand on what this does and how it addresses the OP?