# How to preserve delimeters while using String.split() in Java?

Tags: java

```
String TextValue = "hello{MyVar} Discover {MyVar2} {MyVar3}";
String[] splitString = TextValue.split("\\{*\\}");
```

What I'm getting output is `[{MyVar,  {MyVar2,  {MyVar3]` in `splitString`

But my requirement is to preserve those delimiters `{}` i.e. `[{MyVar},  {MyVar2},  {MyVar3}]`.

Required a way to match above output.

Comment: You could use a regex matcher and get the groups.

Comment: you're getting `[hello{MyVar,  Discover {MyVar2,  {MyVar3]`

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2206378 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3777546

Comment: what exact output did you want ? did you want to remove hello and Discover ?

Answer (score 2):

Use something like so:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\{\\w+\\})");
String str = ...
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Note, the code above is untested but that will look for words within curly brackets and place them in a group. It will then go over the string and output any string which matches the expression above.

An example of the regular expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/lS7cG9/1).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kelvin & npinti.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class CreateMatcherExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String TextValue = "hello{MyVar} Discover {My_Var2} {My_Var3}";
        String patternString = "\\{\\w+\\}";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(TextValue);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 Minor notes: On SO if an answer solves your problem, you mark that answer as correct, posting your solution is usually recommended only if you end up with something different from the provided answers.
Secondly, the code you are using is printing the match by the expression. Although this works, it will break should you add more stuff to the expression which you do not want to have in the end result.